# Why "http://www.stackoverflow.com" is not getting parsed but "http://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial" is getting parsed

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to learn the basic methods of jsoup.I tried to get all the hyperlinks
of a particular web page.But i used [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) link then,i am unable to get all the hyperlinks on that page ,but on the other side when i changed it to
[javatpoint](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial)  it's working.

Can someone explain Why??

Here is the code.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;

import java.io.*;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

class Repo {
    // String html;
    public static void main(String s[]) throws IOException {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial").get();
            // Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com").get();

            System.out.println("doc");
            // Elements link=(Elements)doc.select("span[class]");
            // Elements link = doc.select("span").first();
            // Elements link = (Elements)doc.select("span");
            Elements link = (Elements) doc.select("a[href]");

            for (Element el : link) {
                // System.out.print("-");
                // System.out.println(el.attr("class"));
                String str = el.attr("href");
                System.out.println(str);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case of "stackoverflow" nothing gets printed on the console.

Comment: There is probably an exception, which you skip, so you do not see what the issue is.

Comment: @ hotzst, I added IOException now,so its giving status code=403 error.It means that parsing is forbidden on stackoverflow.Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a way by which i can parse a website which is forbidden ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many websites require valid http requests to carry certain headers. A prominent example is the userAgent header. SO for example will work with this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup
    .connect("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
    .get();
```

*Side note:*
You should **never** try catch exceptions and then silently ignore the possible fail case. At least do some logging there - otherwise your programs will be very hard to debug.

Comment: ,Thanks a lot.I almost lost the hope that i would be able to parse this page.